# Attach the textchanged event only with pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, autopostback, textchanged

Q:

How to make the `TextChanged` for the asp:textbox fires only after pressing `Enter`,not other keys or not when losing the focus?

Comment: You're going the wrong way. You should handle the form submit event instead.

Comment: the text boxes are in the gridview, and the user use `tab` to move among the controls .so i wanna to distinguish between 'tab`,other actions in side and the `Enter` in the other side..

Comment: Sorry still don't get it. Pressing `Enter` inside textbox will submit the form, or in ASP.NET will cause PostBack. What you want to happen instead of this?

Comment: the gridview in an updatepanel. when i press `Enter` in the textbox.the focus goes to the `Update button` in the gridview (in the first row) and save the first record!!!

Comment: And is this the desired behavior or not? Sorry, but I'm not familiar with your project and/or code so though it's clear to you, it's not clear to me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3998/discussion-between-just-name-and-shadow-wizard)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the TextChanged event, and set AutoPostback="false", then it will only check after the form is posted back, not automatically after losing focus. The TextChanged event will fire before your Button Submit.